# Target all page layouts in layout xml file

Tags: magento2, layout

I have a file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <block class="Website\Product\Block\Header" name="header" htmlTag="div" template="Website_Product::phtml/header.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Where `<page layout="1column"...` is there an option to apply to all layouts? `<page layout="*"...?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply a layout file to all layouts you just need to name it `default.xml`

Don't specify the layout in your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <block class="Elcometer\Product\Block\Header" name="elcoheader" htmlTag="div" template="Elcometer_Product::phtml/header.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Please could you elaborate Raphael?

Would that be <page layout="default">

Or

Default.xml:

<page xmlns:xsi=....>
</page?

Comment: @LM_Fielding the **name of your file** must be `default.xml` then whatever the content of this file is, will be applied to all pages

Comment: Sorry I meant to apply to all LAYOUTS not page layouts. Such as 1column, 2column, etc.

Comment: @LM_Fielding what do you mean ? pages can have only one layout you can't apply all layouts to the page

Comment: I want my blocks to apply to all types of pagelayout at that action.

Say it's cms_index_index.xml layout, I want to add a block to the 1column version, 2column, empty, etc..

Is that more clear?

Comment: @LM_Fielding you want your block to be available in every pages in every layout whatever if it's 1column, 2column etc ? right ?

Comment: @LM_Fielding see my update

Comment: Perfect, thanks again. I'm having another problem currently too besides this?

Comment: @LM_Fielding feel free to create a new question ;)